# how can i know the drive free space through Ant script

Tags: ant

Is it possible that we can know the free space of any drive through Ant Script, because I am copying one folder of 300mb size in my deployment ant script so I want to confirm before copy that there is more than 300mb space in that drive.

Comment: basically how can i check the drive size before copy the folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at hasfreespace: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<project name="test" default="test" basedir="."> 

     <target name="test" depends="exists,not-exists">  
          <echo message="Test target"/>
     </target>

     <target name="exists" if="space-exists">  
          <echo message="Space exists"/>
     </target>

     <target name="not-exists" unless="space-exists">  
          <echo message="Space does not exist"/>
     </target>

     <condition property="space-exists"> 
          <!-- Change this to 10000G to see it failing -->
          <hasfreespace partition="/" needed="1M"/>
     </condition>
</project>
```

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\pkumar\Desktop\check_space.xml:4: Problem: failed to create task or type hasfreespace
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: Which version of Ant are you using? hasfreespace is there since 1.7.0. Also, are you using it in a Condition task?

Comment: hi! when i m giving the needed size value as 20.2G it's showing following error~java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20.2"~

Answer (score 0):

I used following approach.

```
<echo message="Checking free space on drive D:" />
<fail message="Drive D: has less than 10 Gb" >
    <condition>
        <not>
            <hasfreespace partition="d:" needed="10G"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>
<echo message="Drive D: has 10 Gb or more" />
```

Script will fail, if drive has less, than 10 GB.